# I want the program to say yes if there is one or more row or column that is filled by stars

Tags: c++

I  want the program to say yes if there is one or more row or column that is filled by stars so my main goal is to have horizontal line of * or a veritcal line of * or more than one

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char    arr[10][10];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++)
        {
            if (arr[x][y] == '*')
            {
                sum = sum + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (sum >= 10)
    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "NO" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you ask questions containing code, please double check to make sure the indentation and spacing is readable, and that *all* code is marked as code (many consecutive blanks lines require more scrolling and can hinder one's ability to see all of the relevant code).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's happening? Do you have example input/output?

Comment: The code doesn't detect rows and columns of stars - it detects if there are 10 stars spread through the array.  You need to loop through the tow and columns - not loop over the entire array.

Comment: /////////*
/////////*
/////////*
/////////*
/////////*
/////////*
/////////*
/////////*
/////////*
/////////*
output
YES
input
**********
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
//////////
output
YES

Comment: jerry how can i do that?

Comment: @ahmedreda Edit your question to provide additional information as asked for. You see in comments it's actually useless/unreadable (intentionally).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here, one of them is that your sum variable isn't accurate. You keep adding to it without resetting it between rows/columns. The other is that you are only checking in one direction, you need to be checking both rows and columns. Consider returning as soon as 10 stars are detected to improve your performance.

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++)
    {
        if (arr[x][y] == '*')
        {
            sum = sum + 1;
            if (sum >= 10)
            {
                cout << "YES" << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would also need to loop in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what your attempt was to do. I'm also providing a non user entered version of your array so you can easily see and test the code with multiple input types. You need to check both row and columns separately. If a star is missing then that row or column was not completely filled with stars.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char arry[10][10] = {
    {'*', '*', '*', ' ', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'},
    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'},
    {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'}
};


int main()
{
    char    arr[10][10];

    /*for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }*/

    bool rowHasStar = true;
    for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
    {
        rowHasStar = true;
        for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++)
        {
            if (arry[x][y] != '*')
            {
                rowHasStar = false;
            }
        }
        if(rowHasStar)
            break;
    }

    bool columnHasStar = true;
    for(int y = 0; y <= 9; y++)
    {
        columnHasStar = true;
        for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
        {
            if (arry[x][y] != '*')
            {
                columnHasStar = false;
            }
        }
        if(columnHasStar)
            break;
    }

    if (rowHasStar || columnHasStar)
    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "NO" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

-This is my first answer! :D

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a `bool` variable:

```
bool column_is_all_stars = true;
for (unsigned int column = 0; column < 10; ++column)
{
    column_is_all_stars = true;
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < 10; ++row)
    {
        if (arr[column][row] != '*')
        {
            column_is_all_stars = false;         
            break; // Column has at least 1 character that is not '*'.
        }
    }
    if (column_is_all_stars)
    {
        cout << "Column " << column << " is all stars.\n";
        break; // A column has been found, no more searching required.
    }
}
```

*Note: you may want to switch the order to `arr[column][row]` depending on how you are ordering things.*

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
        char arr[10][10];
        int RowSum = 0;
        int colSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
                cin >> arr[i][j];
        for (int x = 0; x <= 9 && colSum<10 && RowSum<10; x++)
        {
            RowSum = 0; colSum = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y <= 9 && colSum < 10 && RowSum < 10; y++){
                if (arr[x][y] == '*'){
                    RowSum = RowSum + 1;
                }
                if (arr[y][x] == '*'){
                    colSum = colSum + 1;
                }
            }

        }
        if (colSum == 10 || RowSum == 10)
        {
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "NO" << endl;
        }

        char c = getchar();

        fflush(stdin);
        return 0;
    }
```